# Retrieving the first element of an array of objects in D

Tags: arrays, tuples, d

I am trying to pop off the first element of an array of Tuples. I'm not sure this is the best approach, mostly because it isn't working, but maybe there is a better solution? right now I am trying to use a slice of the 0th element but i keep getting a `Range Violation`. I know there is data in the array, I'm not sure how to deal with this error.

```
auto codersChoice(uint year){
        Tuple!(uint, string, string, double)[] select;

        foreach (i, string geoLocation ; this.map.getLocations){
            auto t = getAllRowsByYearAndCountry(geoLocation, year, i);
            auto slice = t[0 .. 1];
            select ~= slice;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about just select ~= t[0]; // that will get the first element of the array. Also, how do you know there's data in t ? Try putting in if(t.length==0) {continue;}  between "auto t = ..." and "auto slite = ..."

Comment: Also, are you sure geAllRowsByYearAndCountry returns an array of Tuple!(uint, string, string, double) ?

Answer (score 1):

> i keep getting a `Range Violation`. I know there is data in the array, I'm not sure how to deal with this error.
>
> ```
> auto codersChoice(uint year){
>         Tuple!(uint, string, string, double)[] select;
>
>         foreach (i, string geoLocation ; this.map.getLocations){
>             auto t = getAllRowsByYearAndCountry(geoLocation, year, i);
>             auto slice = t[0 .. 1];
>             select ~= slice;
>         }
>     }
> ```

The code you showed throws a `RangeError` when `getAllRowsByYearAndCountry` returns an empty array. Of course, `getAllRowsByYearAndCountry` may throw a `RangeError` itself, too.

If you're sure that `getAllRowsByYearAndCountry` does not return an empty array, then please show more code. Preferably something that compiles, links, and runs (and throws a `RangeError`).